# The socketio can't work in Flask app?

Tags: python, websocket, flask, socket.io

I am writing a small Flask web server, I am using [Flask-SocketIO](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), but the websocket can't work? I can't find the reason.

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', lines=[], currentTime=datetime.utcnow())
    else:
        buy_report = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'buy_report')
        with open(buy_report, 'r') as fread:
            lines = fread.read().decode('gbk').split("\n\n")
            return render_template('index.html', lines = lines, currentTime=datetime.utcnow())


@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    print('received message: ' + message)

class MyFileMonitor(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print event.src_path
        if os.path.basename(event.src_path) == r"buy_report":
            socketio.emit('fileChanged')  //HERE: ###########

if __name__ == '__main__':
    observer = Observer()
    event_handler = MyFileMonitor()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, DIR_PATH, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    socketio.run(app)
```

The front-end code, `monitor.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
     socket.on('connect', function() {
                console.log('connect');
                socket.emit('message', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
            });
});
```

I include this 'monitor.js':

```
{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src={{ url_for('static', filename = 'monitor.js') }}></script>

{% endblock %}
```

But i find `console.log('connect');` is not executed.
Who can help me?

Comment: Can you add the `<script>` tag that imports the socketio client to your front-end snippet?

Comment: Hmm. Okay, that looks good. Any errors in the browser's console log?

Comment: `XHR finished loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/1/?t=1425272721171".
XHR finished loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:5000/".
jquery.min.js:4 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js XHR finished loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/monitor.js?_=1425272721034".`, just this. I think this is not error.

Comment: @Miguel Becasue i use `watchdog` to monitor file change, when file changed, i will omit `socketio.emit('fileChanged') `. But the `watchdog` runing in another thread, i don't know if this is the root cause.

Comment: Does the example app work for you? https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/tree/master/example

Comment: @Miguel I change `io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);` to `io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');`. it can connect successfully. But this code `socketio.emit('fileChanged', namespace='/test') ` is still not ok, the front cann't receive this event.